# Does anyone know if there a .NET API for Project Natal?

Tags: .net, xbox360

I have just discovered Project Natal from Microsoft, it looks pretty cool and was wondering if there was any starting points for developers to get into it?

Answer (score 2):

At this point, I don't think so. Remember, project natal is still in Alpha or Pre-Alpha and won't be released for at least 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's already a developer package out there... But, It's for developers only. Anyway It's too early for thinking about an API. Maybe they're fixing other kind of legal stuff with patent registrations, researching and posting rumors on the net right now, before even thinking on the API release.

I'm guessing on a XNA module for project Natal (or whatever nave gets at the end). At least for all the community, and a full API (probably with greater low-level manipulation) for developers.